# Wix Installer - how to run a custom action just after rollback happened?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have created a Wix installer having multiple functionalities like deploying a service to Tomcat, Add and update config file of service at tomcat server and some other, Creating Web application at IIS, Creating MongoDB etc.
So to do some update config kind of task I have written custom actions with deferred execution, sometimes due to some reason custom action get failed and it causes to Rollback and sometimes this rollback leaves some footprints like service at Tomcat or other configuration files or may want to remove Mongo DB etc.

SO here I want to remove left footprints using a custom action just after rollback happened.

I have added a custom action `Execute="rollback"` and calling it `Before="Installfinalize"`, But it's just calling before rollback happened.

Is there any way to deal smartly with such kind of situation?

Answer (score 1):

[Rollback custom actions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371369) only execute after a failure has occurred, and only the subset that were scheduled before the error. Assuming you need elevated privileges, they are your only clean option, so I would start with verifying the order of your actions' scheduling.

There's one more place you can *try* to run an action after rollback occurs: as the end of the [Install UI Sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369543). When an error occurs in an installation that's showing full UI, it will then run UI sequence entry `msiDoActionStatusFailure` (-3). Typically this shows a dialog box explaining that the installation (or uninstallation) failed. And it's hard to do more, as properties do not flow back from the execute sequence to the UI sequence.

In theory you can schedule any action at that entry in order to do something first. However, this action will run with the same privileges as the UI (typically limited), and will only run when the UI is shown. So this probably will not help your scenario. (Also, unless you're careful, you'll mess up the expected UI experience if you fail to invoke the dialog box it would otherwise show.)